# install an app automatically while installing another one

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

i need some informations about how to install an app from google play store, and install another app automatically with it , example of `Big Launcher`, when you download & install the app, another app called `Big Dailer` is installed automatically , and when you uninstall the `Big Launcher` , the app `Big Dailer` is uninstalled too ( automatically ) , do you have any idea about how to do that ? because i have two applications which depends on each other and i want to install the second one automatically while installing the first one.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not automatically install a second app.

This is the system playing 'tricks' on you. You can define, in your manifest file, a second main launcher activity, with its own launcher icon.

So basically, you download 1 app with 2 entry points. From there, you can choose to handle that as 2 different apps. So from ActivityLaunch1 you can access Activities 1 to 5, and from ActivityLaunch2 you can access Activities 6 to 10  per example.

For the user, this looks as if you've got 2 apps at once.

Comment: and the memory allowed to those installed "apps" , is the system will allocate just 16mb for the whole "apps" , or each LauncherActivity will consider it as an app and it will have it's own allocated memory  ?

Comment: You're simply 1 app, with all the rules and limits of 1 app.